"Access" the devtools network information
currently i'm trying to get "access" to the network tab in the devtools of Google Chrome and want to fetch there some XHR / Redirect information. I was testing my Code and I can get access to the regular devtools with the elements.
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()         
chrome_options.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")
   
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://google.com/")
time.sleep(20)

Can anyone help me to get access to the network tab (in the example above of Google) and check if there are XHR / redirect information available?
TIA


It auto-opens the dev tools. Just head over to the "network" tab. It could be hidden if it didn't show because there is insufficient space. Try pressing the arrow to choose the tab.
For XHR / redirect information, press the filter, e.g., Fetch/XHR button.

Thanks for your response. Unfortunately it is not what I was looking for. I want to adjust my Python Code that the network tab is opend automaticaly. So the example above opens the "Elements" tab and I want to navigate to the "Network" Tab :)
